# SQL Server 2012 Memory usage

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Since i upgraded to SQL Server 2012 I've noticed that it almost doesn't consume any memory at all. Before when i used SQL Server 2008 R2 it used at least 2-4 GB of RAM and now it only used like 150 MB or something.

I haven't really noticed any performance problem or something like that and i'm just curious if they changed something and that you can't look at the SQL Server process to see memory usage anymore or something?

I have of course tried to Google it but hasn't found anything useful.

Comment: Where exactly are you looking to see memory usage? (If task manager, what is the exact column name?)

Comment: Its sqlservr.exe  http://screencast.com/t/UncBHzC30X

Comment: that doesn't show the name of the column that 120,920 KB is in

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is because your running SQL server under an account which locks pages in memory, e.g. system account.

If so then you will see SQL using very little memory in task manager, however using a tool like RAMMAP shows that an amount of memory consumed by AWE (please see below). In SQL 2012 this happens on 64 bit instances.

Running DBCC memorystatus will indeed show that the memory consumed by AWE is being allocated by SQL.

[image]